# elastic search nested filter

Tags: json, elasticsearch, nested, logz.io

Here is the structure of a document, as returned by the Elastic Search API:

`{
    "process_name":"process01",
    "beat":
        {
        "hostname":"12345","name":"blablabla"
        },
}`

Filtering by process_name was easy, but how can I filter by host_name, which is nested inside beat?

- Failed attempt 1

`{
    "size":10000,
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "should": [
                { "match" : { "process_name" : "process01" } },
                { "match" : { "process_name" : "process02" } }
                    ],
            "must": [
                 { "match" : { beat: { "hostname":"12345" } } }
                     ]
        }
    }
}`

error message 1:

> (failed to deserialize object type=class com.logshero.api.SearchApiRequest):

- Failed attempt 2

`{
    "size":10000,
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "should": [
                { "match" : { "process_name" : "process01" } },
                { "match" : { "process_name" : "process02" } }
                    ],
            "must": [
                 { "match" : { "hostname":"12345" } }
                     ]
        }
    }
}`

error message 2:

> {"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following query. You also have to make sure that beat in your mappings is defined as nested type.

```
{
    "size": 10000,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                "match": {
                    "process_name": "process01"
                }
            }, {
                "match": {
                    "process_name": "process02"
                }
            }],
            "must": [{
                "match": {
                    "beat.hostname": "12345"
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks